# Can't setup Python venv on new Mac

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have miniconda installed on my new Mac at:

```
/opt/miniconda3/bin/python
```

My .zsh terminal shows the default Python as 2.7:

```
Python 2.7.16 (default, Dec 21 2020, 23:00:36) 
[GCC Apple LLVM 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.30.4) [+internal-os, ptrauth-isa=sign+stri on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I am trying to create a venv for a project I want to work on in VSCode.  I am navigating to the folder and typing:

```
20:38:54:~/Documents/Python_Projects/pword_proj % pip3 install virtualenv
```

and I get this error:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

I also tried:

```
20:39:40:~/Documents/Python_Projects/pword_proj % pip install virtualenv
```

and I get this error:

```
zsh: command not found: pip
```

I am not sure what I am doing incorrect here.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python version 2.7 has been depreciated and so pip3 is now being used. You can try installing virtualenv with brew:

```
brew install pyenv-virtualenv
```

You can install home-brew here https://brew.sh

You may also need to reinstall the CommandLineTools using:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I don't understand brew at all, I tried installing it when I got the laptop and made a mess of it so I removed it.  I think the second part of your answer may be the issue from what I am googling around.  Maybe Ill try that sudo command, it's possible the last Mac OS update screwed up those tools

Comment: What types of problems did you have when you tried to install brew originally?

Comment: I don't remember to be honest, just a bunch of error messages trying to get it installted correctly.  I don't know why.  Anyway, your Xcode fix seems to have resolved the issue. At least pip is working now.  Thanks Jacob

Answer (score 2):

If you already have miniconda installed, I do not believe you need virtualenv since miniconda allows you to use conda environments. [Conda does what virtualenv can do and more.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34398794/10084882)

You can learn more about managing conda environments here. To create a conda environment, you can use the following command.

```
conda create --name myenv
```

That being said, it seems that your shell is not recognizing the `pip` command. This may be due to not being in your base conda environment, so enable that by using

```
source activate
```

If `pip` still isn't found after that, I would recommend checking your environment variables under [PATH](https://imstudio.medium.com/path-macos-best-practice-for-path-environment-variables-on-mac-os-35ec4076a486).