# Conda vs. pip under Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, conda, spyder

I have a 2-part question about conda vs. pip virtual environments. I found great information on the answers [What is the difference between pip and conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda/68897551#68897551) and [Does Conda replace the need for virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398676/does-conda-replace-the-need-for-virtualenv/49084152#49084152) but still have something unclear.

I have a given python project (say PR) that I need to install and further develop on a linux server (say S) where python is installed with anaconda. Now, the usage/installation instructions of PR tell me to use python to create virtual environment and pip to install all packages. That is,

`python3 -m venv PR`

`pip install --editable .`  (the dot included at the end)

According to ["pip install --editable ./" vs "python setup.py develop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306099/pip-install-editable-vs-python-setup-py-develop) the latter reads the file `setup.py` (included in PR) which contains a function `setup(...)` with option `install_requires` listing all the required packages and installs them automatically. I have tested this on my own computer (which does not have conda) and it works fine. At least no error messages.

Now I need to further develop PR on S. My question Part 1: can I use conda instead of pip to create and update virtual environment? If yes, what would be the conda command replacing `pip install --editable .` ?   I'm positive I will later need to install other packages as well. I'm worried about conflicts between conda/pip.

On S, I have Spyder and no other python IDEs. I have never used Spyder but I'm very familiar with PyCharm (Windows) and VS Code (Linux) so I assume debugging with Spyder will be similar to those. My question Part 2 (tied to Part 1): if I have to use pip to install packages, does Spyder see those? Or can it only see conda-installed packages?

(**Edit/update**): Thank you Carlos for comments. I continue my question:

I created and activated the virtual environment (VE) with conda

```
conda create PR_venv
conda activate PR_venv
```

Installed pip with

```
conda install pip
```

(this upgraded pip and installed several other packages too, including newer version of python). Installed PR and its required packages with pip

```
pip install -e .
```

Now, if I run the PR package inside this active VE interactively from the terminal, everything works fine. I would like to do the same from within spyder, to get the IDE debugging abilities in my hand.

When I start spyder, open a python file to be run, click "Run" button, it crashes in the import statements.
Spyder cannot see the installed packages. It can see only the local package PR but none of the packages installed by pip for this VE.

I am not sure what is the correct question here; I'm confused how are conda VEs related to spyder/jupyter/ipython ? I cannot find information in the conda documents about this.
I cannot find from spyder documents anything about VEs. Do I have to somehow re-install the packages (how?) inside Spyder? It seems pointless because the packages are installed already.

(**Edit/Update 2**): The information on https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html makes me even more confused: Spyder is presented as *both* a stand-alone program *and* as a python package. So do I have to re-install Spyder inside the VE(?!) with

```
conda activate PR_venv
conda install spyder
```

Any clarification would be appreciated. I have always thought that the IDEs are stand-alone programs and that's it. This Spyder setup twists my brains into pretzel.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. 1) "should I use conda or python/pip to create and update virtual environment?" is only opinion based. 2) Please ask only one question at once

Comment: @FlyingTeller Thanks, I have reformulated the first part of the question. But I think this really is one question with 2 parts: they are so intertwined that I don't see sense splitting them into 2 separate posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1**: yes I can use conda to create VE and pip to install packages

```
conda create PR_venv
conda activate PR_venv
conda install pip
pip install --editable .
conda list
```

The last line shows which packages are installed by `conda` and which by `pip` (shown as `pypi`)

**Part 2**: spyder by default cannot see the packages. Need to do two things:

```
conda install spyder-kernels
```

Open Spyder and Tools > Preferences > Python Interpreter > Use the following interpreter > [full path to VE python command]

Restart Spyder. Now it can see the packages.

(Edit:) this link is great: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) About your questions:

> can I use conda instead of pip to create and update virtual environment?

Yes, you can. Please see [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) to learn about the functionality offered by conda for managing environments.

> If yes, what would be the conda command replacing `pip install --editable .` ?

Conda doesn't offer a good replacement for that command. However, you can still use it in a conda environment, as long as all you've installed all your package dependencies with conda before running it. That would avoid mixing conda and pip packages, which usually leads to really bad results.

> if I have to use pip to install packages, does Spyder see those? Or can it only see conda-installed packages?

Spyder can work with pip and conda packages without problems. Just make sure of not mixing them (as I said above) and you'll be fine. In addition, please read [our documentation](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/ipythonconsole.html#connect-to-a-remote-kernel) to learn how to connect a local Spyder instance to a remote server.